# What is the difference between these two pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure

In linked list I came across the following structures

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};      
struct node *list;
```

What is the difference between `list` and `next`?

Comment: Do you mean difference between `list` pointer and `next` pointer?

Answer (score 1):

They are both pointers to the `struct node`.

But the difference is that `next` is a member of the struct while `list` is an object.

That means that you can use `list` as

```
list->data;
```

But to use `next`, you need to use

```
list->next->data;
```

or

```
struct node a;
a.next->data;
```

That is, it behaves like needs an object just like any other members of the struct.

You can refer this [code](http://ideone.com/iCNgVt)

Answer (score 0):

**> There is no difference between these Two Pointers both are refrences
and store the adress of the object.**
but the *next behaves as the variable of the struct and the other pointer behaves as an object of the Struct.

Comment: As it stands the answer is not correct. An instance of `next` would **reference** `struct node` **not be** a `struct node`, the same applies to  `list` with the difference that is does reference a `struct node`, but not only would.

Comment: @alk But `list` isn't a `struct node` it also references a `struct node`.

Comment: Both are refrences but next help us to make a linklist and the list refrence behave as a head.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all in the snippet shown there only "exists" **one** pointer, that is `list`.

However:

- `list` is an instance of a pointer pointing to `struct node`. It uses memory.
- `next` is a member of, part of the definition of the type `struct node` and of type pointer to `struct node`. `next` is no instance of a pointer. It does not use memory.

Comment: What you mean by "instance of a pointer"? They're both pointers to a `struct node`

Comment: `list` use memory, `next` doesn't. @AlejandroDíaz

Comment: don't they both use `sizeof(struct node*)`? `struct node *list;` isn't allocating any memory.

Comment: No, `next` is just part of a defintion. As the code stands `next` (as well as `data`) do not occupying any memory.

Comment: `list->next` does use memory, the same amount as `list`. @AlejandroDíaz

Comment: Ok, I think the question might be understood both ways.

Answer (score 0):

The Both pointers list and next are pointing to node structure.

> The Main Difference is:
>
> **list** is not part of the structure node, where as **next** is part of the structure node.